# How to check connection to network drive?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have an application that chronically creates/writes files on my network drive using `WNetAddConnection2()`.

```
    NETRESOURCE nr = {0,};
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY; 
    nr.lpLocalName = nullptr; 
    nr.lpRemoteName = L"\\\\MyNetworkDrive\\MyFolder\\"; 
    nr.lpProvider = nullptr; 

    DWORD ret = WNetAddConnection2 (&nr, L"MyPW", L"MyID", CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE); //add connection

    // A few seconds needed to invoke StartWritingFiles();    

    StartWritingFiles();
```

But `WNetAddConnection2` seems to require such heavy job to return, which makes the application look frozen.

So I suppose that I'd be able to **avoid calling it when the connection to MyNetworkDrive is alive**.

Which API am I supposed to look for to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thread off the network operations.

Comment: @MartinJames Then is there no way to figure out whether the connection is alive or not?

Comment: First as suggested by "Martin James", you should use a separate thread. Second, did you try `GetFileAttributes`? If the network connection is not active or network drive is not available `GetLastError()` will return ERROR_BAD_NETPATH.

Comment: Any access to a network drive can potentially block (for an extended period), that's why it's good to always do it on a non-UI thread if possible.

Comment: Thanks. I will try threading off the specific process!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments above are correct. Network stuff should not be done on a UI thread. BUT, in case you don't want to thread, I believe you want to enumerate all the open connections to see if the resource you want is connected. Try WNetOpenEnum like so:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <windows.h>
#include <Winnetwk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Mpr.lib")

VOID main(){

    HANDLE hEnum = (HANDLE)0;

    DWORD dwError = WNetOpenEnum(RESOURCE_CONNECTED,RESOURCETYPE_DISK,0,NULL,&hEnum);

    if (dwError == NO_ERROR){

        DWORD dwCount = -1;

        CHAR szBuff[1000];

        ZeroMemory(szBuff,sizeof(szBuff));

        DWORD dwSize = sizeof(szBuff);

        dwError = WNetEnumResource(hEnum,&dwCount,szBuff,&dwSize);

        if (dwError == NO_ERROR){

            NETRESOURCE *pnr = (NETRESOURCE*)szBuff;

            for (DWORD d = 0; d < dwCount; d++){

                if (pnr[d].lpRemoteName){

                    printf("%s\n",pnr[d].lpRemoteName);

                }

            }

        }

        WNetCloseEnum(hEnum);

    }else{

        printf("Failed: %u\n",dwError);

    }

}
```

This is a little hackish because I'm assuming all the connections fit in 1000 bytes. You can read about the function WNetOpenEnum and related here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385478%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have now one more option other than threading off, which still is not a bad idea though.